# How to change text names inside select box without changing selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

For example, in code below when I select `Ship Date`, I want the "Sort Direction" to change to `{"Earliest Date First", "Latest Date First"}` without changing the selection itself.

And when I select "Value", I want the "Sort Direction" to change to `{"Smallest Value First", "Largest Date First"}` without changing the selection.

So I want the *text* of options to change in select box #2, when I select various specific options in select box #1.

How?

My code does something weird and does not change selection...

```js
$('#sort_by').change(function() {
  if ($('#sort_by').val("shipdate"))
    $('#sort_order').val("asc").val("Earliest Date First");
  else
    $('#sort_order').val("desc").val("Latest Date First");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Sort By Field:
  <select name="sort_by" id="sort_by">
    <option value="shipdate">Ship Date</option>
    <option value="value">Value</option>
  </select>
  <br/>Sort Direction:
  <select name="sort_order" id="sort_order">
    <option value="asc">Asc</option>
    <option value="desc">Desc</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just only want to change the text of your options you need to simply change the text.

Example :https://jsfiddle.net/799cf2wr/

```
<form>
  Sort By Field:
  <select name="sort_by" id="sort_by">
    <option value="shipdate">Ship Date</option>
    <option value="value">Value</option>
  </select>
  <br/>Sort Direction:
  <select name="sort_order" id="sort_order">
    <option value="asc" id="asc">Asc</option>
    <option value="desc" id="desc">Desc</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#sort_by').change(function() {
  if ($('#sort_by').val() === "shipdate"){
        $('#asc').text("Earliest Date First");
        $('#desc').text("Latest Date First");
  }
  else{
      $('#asc').text("Smallest Value First");
      $('#desc').text("Largest Date First");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, mate https://jsfiddle.net/bimbonkens/no7nqgzg/

You need to change the inner html, not the val() and you do it like this

```
$('#sort_by').change(function() {
  var asc = $('option[value=asc]', '#sort_order');
  var desc = $('option[value=desc]', '#sort_order');

  if ($(this).val() == 'shipdate') {
    asc.html('Earliest Date First');
    desc.html('Latest Date First');
  } else if($(this).val() == 'value') {
    asc.html('Smallest Value First');
    desc.html('Largest Date First');
  } 
});
```

Comment: I was writing exactly the same, except he can use .text instead of .html

Comment: nice. 10 answers in the race for reputation, all mostly the same :)

Comment: @Bimbonkens if he wants to change the value of the option each time as well, then for the next change your select will not work.

Comment: lol, i posted mine as well because deleting it felt like a waste of my time; but i also upvoted you

Comment: @Matt.kaaj you are right, but from the question i got that he needed to change the text of his options depending on the context, but values stay the same - ascending/descending. It was a very simple answer doing exactly what OP asked, and i know it could use lots of improvement to make it more universal :)

Comment: the question itself is pretty strange, i don't really get what the OP is trying to accomplish here

Answer (score 1):

You can change the selected option value simply by calling `val()` on the `select` form control.

To change the text of a specific value without actually changing the value use `text()` on that specific option using the proper selector - aka `$('#sort_order option[value="asc"]')`

And if you don't want to change the currently selected value then just take out the lines that set the `sort_order` `val`

```js
$('#sort_by').change(function() {
  if ($('#sort_by').val() == "shipdate") {
    $('#sort_order').val("asc");
    $('#sort_order option[value="asc"]').text("Earliest Date First")
  }
  else {
    $('#sort_order').val("desc");
    $('#sort_order option[value="desc"]').text("Latest Date First");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Sort By Field:
  <select name="sort_by" id="sort_by">
    <option value="shipdate">Ship Date</option>
    <option value="value">Value</option>
  </select>
  <br/>Sort Direction:
  <select name="sort_order" id="sort_order">
    <option value="asc">Asc</option>
    <option value="desc">Desc</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sort_by').change(function() {
    var sort_order = $('#sort_order');
    var sort_order_asc = sort_order.find('option[value="asc"]');
    var sort_order_desc = sort_order.find('option[value="desc"]');
    if ($('#sort_by').val("shipdate")) {
        sort_order_asc.text("Earliest Date First");
        sort_order_desc.text("Latest Date First");
    } else {
        sort_order_asc.text("Asc");
        sort_order_desc.text("Desc");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a value, use

```
$('selector').val()
```

And to change the value, use

```
$('selector').val("new value")
```

So, for your code, it should be

```
if ($('#sort_by').val() == "shipdate")
  $('#sort_order').val("asc");
else
  $('#sort_order').val("desc");
```

Note that you only need .val("asc") to set the value

https://jsfiddle.net/c8mb23vg/

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set the value of the input to the `option`'s `value`, not it's label.  It will automatically show the corresponding label.

Also, to *get* the value of an input, just call `.val()`.  If you provide an argument, it will *set* the input.

So what you're doing was always setting the value of `#sort_by` to "shipdate" instead of checking it.

But you're actually asking about just changing the labels of the other dropdown's options -- select each option and change it's `text` instead of `val`.

You'll also want to update the initial labels to match the default selection of the first dropdown (i.e. start with date labels since the date option is the first dropdown).

```js
$('#sort_by').change(function() {
  var $me = $(this), $other = $('#sort_order');
  if ($me.val() == "shipdate") {
    $other.find('option[value="asc"]').text('Earliest Date First');
    $other.find('option[value="desc"]').text('Latest Date First');
  }
  else {
    $other.find('option[value="asc"]').text('Asc');
    $other.find('option[value="desc"]').text('Desc');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Sort By Field:
  <select name="sort_by" id="sort_by">
    <option value="shipdate">Ship Date</option>
    <option value="value">Value</option>
  </select>
  <br/>Sort Direction:
  <select name="sort_order" id="sort_order">
    <option value="asc">Earliest Date First</option>
    <option value="desc">Latest Date First</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Lol, You beat me 12 seconds.

Comment: sorry but I meant something else ... I want the "asc" to change to "Earliest" when "Shipt Date" is selected. (and "asc" to change to "Smallest" when "Value" is selected)  The choice (selection, option) should remain unchanged, just the text of the option should change

Comment: @Dennis thank you for the clarification, updated accordingly